# How to select a particular div at my own level

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have :

```
<div class=mystyle>
    <input type=checkbox>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
         .....
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>

    <div>// this is what I want 
    </div>


</div>
```

I want to create a css style to be applied to the last div at the same level of  element or also can be the second div ...

I think I could use [attribute] approach but... Is there any way to use another selector ? 
It is possible I could have more than one input-div-div structure inside mystyle input:checked  ?

Comment: _at the same level_ of which element?

Comment: Of the input element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use

```
input ~ div:last-of-type {
   color: green;
}
```

this selector will pick the last sibling `div` of your `input`

example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvwEoB